# Removing unnecessary spaces after output

Tags: python

I am trying to remove the spaces that appear after the output of the code. I have tried to use the .rstrip but it doesn't seem to work.

The coding is:

```
msg = Tjghksikdsiiireskfafslweicfnareodorffqecproerdtre
var1 = 0
var2 = 1
for i in range(len(msg)):
  print(msg[var1:var2], end=' ')
  var1 = int(var1) + 3
  var2 = int(var2) + 3
```

It produces the correct coding apart from that it has lots of extra spaces at the end. Is there a way to fix this?

The output produces:

```
T h i s i s a l i n e o f c o d e
```

like it is supposed to but it adds alot of spaces after. Please help.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it very clear. I want the spaces between the letters but after the "e" it prints around 20 unnecessary spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the extra spaces are because you are trying to print every third character but it is repeating once for every character, you can just change your for loop to this:

```
for i in range( int(len(msg) /3) +1):
```